# Know currently loaded WebPage in Browser Android.

Tags: android, browser

I am designing app in which I want to track the user seen website and pop up window when he/she opens restricted website so how can I monitor sites in Android Default WebBrowser?

Comment: There is no way to know the activities of the Android default Browser